# Grails define or get global variable for action and controller name

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to define a variable that contains the action name and controller name. This variable will be used in logging.

Here is my controller:

```
class SomeController {
 def TAG = "${controllerName}/${actionName}"
 // rest of code
}
```

Above code will not work as actionName is not known when the gString is evaluated.

So what I have to do at this moment, is that in each action of controller, I have to put this in place:

```
class SomeController {

 // .....     

 def someAction() {
   def TAG = "${controllerName}/${actionName}"
   // rest of code
   log.debug("${TAG}: logging message")
 }
}
```

So I basically want is to avoid having to define the `TAG` in each action. Is there a way to simply define it as a global variable(or otherwise) once so that I can call it in each action for logging as in above code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I figured it out. I used [lazy evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29364561/1291122) to declare the TAG as a closure:

```
class SomeController {
 def TAG = "${-> controllerName}/${-> actionName}"
 // rest of code
}
```

Hope it helps somebody else too!!